# Как написать финальный класс, чтобы он не мог использоваться в качестве базового класса

Tags: c++

Сразу можно ответить, что нужно определить класс со спецификатором `final`. Этот спецификатор был введен в стандарт `С++11`. А если компилятор очень старый?.. Или же  хочется знать  как это делали до 2011 _ го года?  Как можно написать класс `Target`, чтобы он не мог использоваться как базовый, **не используя** спецификатор `final`?

Comment: Я думаю только класс-фабрика поможет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184133/prevent-class-inheritance-in-c

Comment: @user7860670, я пропустил ваш комментарий, поэтому удалю свой ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Вот такой вариант придумал:

```
template <typename T>
class FinalBase
{
    friend T;
    FinalBase() = default;
    FinalBase(const FinalBase &) = default;
    FinalBase &operator=(const FinalBase &) = default;
};

#ifndef NDEBUG
#define FINAL(...) __VA_ARGS__ : virtual FinalBase<__VA_ARGS__>
#else
#define FINAL(...) __VA_ARGS__
#endif

struct FINAL(A) // Вместо `struct A final`.
{

};

struct B : A
{

};
```

Здесь, из-за виртуального наследования, конструкторы `B` будут пытаться вызвать конструкторы `FinalBase<A>` напрямую. Но не смогут, потому что те приватные.

В коде выше ошибки нет, но она возникнет, если попытаться создать объект `B`:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'B'
note: default constructor of 'B' is implicitly deleted because base class 'FinalBase<A>' has
    an inaccessible default constructor
```

Или если попытаться написать конструктор для `B`:

```
error: inherited virtual base class 'FinalBase<A>' has private default constructor
```

Поскольку виртуальное наследование увеличивает размер класса, добавил проверку `#ifndef NDEBUG`, чтобы отключать его в релизной сборке.

Comment: Используя эти идеи, можно сделать проще, что я и сделал _ спасибо.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Так поделитесь..

Comment: @Mikhailo, я поделился, а потом удалил ответ, так как по ссылке в комментарий от   user7860670, дан тот же ответ